# Schmitt trigger resistance

Tags: resistors, comparator, schmitt-trigger

[image]

I was thrown off by a certain website while learning about a op amp Schmitt trigger design. The layout was the same inverting config as the above schematic but gave a confusing answer to calculating high threshold.

Vout=5v high
Vout=0v low
Vref=5v

For the Vout low hysteresis the calc was:

(R2||R3)/(R1+R2||R3)*Vref

For Vout high hysteresis was

(R3)/(R3+R1||R2)*Vref

Vout low made sense, but if Vout high was 5v I would have thought it would be (R2)/(R2+R3||R1)*Vref.

When I checked online calculator apparently I was correct. Can anyone set the record straight? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low threshold value is indeed

\$V_{low} = (R2||R3)/(R1+R2||R3)*V_{ref}\$

If the comparator is active high then the hysteresis offset is

\$V_{hys} =(R1||R2)/(R3+R1||R2)*V_{OutHigh}\$

So

\$V_{high} = V_{low} + V_{hys}\$

Assuming \$V_{ref}\$ is low resistance and \$V_{OutLow} = 0V\$

If the comparator is open collector then

\$V_{high} = V_{ref} * R2/(R1+R2)\$

Comment: Try multiplying the final formula by Vref (or just see my answer LOL).

Comment: @Andyaka yup, I know, but you didn't add the formula for active high which where I was originally headed....

Comment: Thank you both. I suppose what I had in mind which was neglected on the schematic I found (my fault) is a pull up resistor at output to 5v rail. Does that bring R3 into the equation like I had?

Comment: @Archaeus with a pullup R4 add it to R3 in the Vhys equation

Comment: @Trevor Assuming the active high comparator, the calculator I checked and my formula matches your Vlow+Vhys for Vhigh. Works for me. I'll give you the bump for the different configs in your answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that the formula given is wrong.

For a proper comparator (with open collector output), the upper limit is: -

\$\dfrac{V_{REF} \cdot R2}{R1+R2}\$

If the device is in fact an op-amp then the upper limit will involve the positive supply rail.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the other answers.

- use Vref, R1,R2 to get Veq & Req equivalent series source.
- if Veq is set to output midpoint = input midpoint

  - e.g. 2.5V=Veq and Req=1/2*R1
- then Vin(+)= Req/(Req+R3)* |(Vout-Veq)|
- entering your output state for Vout then defines your upper and lower limits, such as 1% and 33%, two common thresholds for different applications.
- also CMOS schmitt gates are high input impedance with 1/3 to 2/3 Vdd thresholds, nom.
- but here with a rail to rail comparator to use 1/3 and 2/3 Vdd for thresholds.(nominal) you set R3=R1=**R**

  - then Vin(+)will have a Vpp hysteresis of 1/3 Vdd centered at Vdd/2

but I could be wrong .. I"m having coffee and carrot cake at an outdoor cafe.  But Vin+ is a result of R1,2,3 and Vout and Vref=Vout max

Comment: Lol thanks Tony. The last part made made me chuckle. Enjoy the cake